# how to get over these maven/m2eclipse issues

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

(first, I admit, I have no love for maven/m2eclipse, but it wouldn't be that bad if I could figure out how to overcome these issues)

I am using maven/m2eclipse.  m2eclipse is the only good way I know of to suck in the maven jars.  Some of these may not have solutions(but I am hoping to be surprised).  Maybe solving #9 solves them all?

ISSUES

1. When I run "mvn clean package", I am dead in the water as far as running a unit test in eclipse while maven is building as I LOVE to multitask but maven prevents me here.  How to get around this?
2. I move eclipse to point to eclipsegen/classes but then the unit tests are still using the classes in target/classes so it's not using my latest code that I just edited in eclipse and debugging is not lining up and it's stepping on blank lines that don't have code.
3. If I just slightly touch the pom.xml, bam, it builds when I don't really want it to and turning of automatic builds did not seem to help.
4. On top of #3, I get random pom builds downloading jars which just freezes eclipse from doing anything why the jars are being downloaded(I am a bit multitasker so this frustrates me to no end)
5. If I want to modify or do something really custom I need, the answer is usually create a java plugin but this then would require me to create another source control project with another automated build making sure the build tags all versions so we can reproduce issues with certain versions.  (in ant, I just modify the xml to do custom stuff).
6. (I hear there is a bug open for 5 years on this one).  global exclusions because people on our project keep breaking stuff when they include new things that depend on log4j and sucking that library in breaks us so we want to globally exclude it so people stop breaking the project when adding new things (IVY has global exclusions, why doesn't maven!!!!)
7. The xml code for generation from an xsd in maven is about 2-3 times the code of doing it in ant.  Why is this?  That really shouldn't be the case I think.
8. Running my unit test says xxxx-12.0.8-SNAPSHOT is missing but in my pom.xml it clearly says 12.0.9-SNAPSHOT not .8.  ie. m2eclipse gets into some weird state and I get screwed wasting yet more time because someone selected maven
9. (I don't like IvyDE for the same reasons I don't like m2eclipse).  In maven, is there any way like in Ivy to say on a build MOVE ALL jars into target/lib so that I can uninstall m2eclipse(if maven had this one feature, I think all my problems might go away)....That IS AN Ivy feature that rocks by the way!!!!
   NOTE: I just realized that uninstalling m2eclipse and running "mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse" is not really an option since on this project I had to import 30 projects.  I think on single projects, that is a great solution.
10. Is there no way like ant to log the command that was run for debugging purposes? ( [in maven how to log the command that was run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259918/in-maven-how-to-log-the-command-that-was-run) )

I should really look into gradle(I hear it's best of maven and ant) as the theory of maven sounded great but you can tell there was a lot of controversy over it(which usually indicates a bad tool).  Good tools that really help typically do have some controversy, but not as much as maven has had so it makes me think twice as I don't want to screw the guy who takes over my project(and I know ant will work).  Many people I think don't even consider that.  They think "I am fine, so why won't the next guy be fine".

Any ideas on how to fix the above issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About #9, if you have 2 alternatives :

- Execute

  > mvn dependency:copy-dependencies

  See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html for customization options. You'll have to set your Eclipse classpath manually to point to the newly copied jars.
- Use JBoss Tools JDT Extensions to get the "Materialize Library" feature (see http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/core/core-news-3.3.0.M4.html). You'll basically just have to right-click on the Maven Classpath library, select a destination folder, select (and rename) the jars you want, and you'll get a m2e-free project in Eclipse (still a valid Maven project in command line though).
  You can install JBoss Tools JDT Extensions from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I like Maven and M2Eclipse, and I have not experienced any of the issues that you mention. In general, M2Eclipse does not get in the way much for the way I'm working.

One thing that might help is disabling the *Maven Builder* for the projects (right-click the project, select "Properties", then "Builders"). This will get rid of many of the issues you're complaining about.

One other thing that might help you (and comes close to #9 on your list: Uninstall M2Eclipse and use `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, which will generate Eclipse `.project` and `.classpath` files, which include all dependencies as Eclipse project dependencies. Whenever you add or change dependencies, you will have to run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` again. Give this a try...

Comment: ugh, we have 30 projects(I don't particularly like the environment setup that was done here).

Answer (score 0):

Although it does sound like a faster PC would solve some of your issues I do agree that the m2eclipse plugin sucks (although it sucks a little less since eclipse indigo). Because of this I switched to using Intellij for a while but I switched back to eclipse after a month (for me, eclipse is still the best in spite of m2eclipse).

I use m2eclipse to be able to work in eclipse but nothing more. All my maven builds (package, install, whatever) I run with maven itself (command line) simply because there have been too many occasions where the result was different (working in one, not in the other and and maven was always correct).

So, sorry, no direct answers to your questions, just some tips:

1) do it outside eclipse
2) stick to maven standards (target/classes); that will make your life a lot easier
6) using dependency management in a parent pom might help a bit
8) if you get the same issue when running from command line then there is a problem in your pom (resolve using mvn dependency:tree), if not, see 1
9) maybe assembly is an option here but I would not recommend your approach

Comment: I can't do #1 outside eclipse as I am trying to debug the test which I can't do with maven ;).  yup, #2 I had to backout my changes back to target/classes instead of having eclipse use a different dir than maven.  (#6 - how does parent pom help with parent exclusions?  how do you do that?)  #8...mvn works fine outside eclipse...only inside eclipse it is broken :( and I have to run mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse to fix it.

Comment: I have a very fast MacBook Pro with 8 gig of memory so not sure a faster pc will do much good.

Comment: Still strange that your eclipse 'hangs' while doing a maven build. If have about 80 projects open on a weaker PC and don't have such issues. #6 parent pom won't provide global exclusions but if you define a dependency in the dependencyManagement + add the exclusions there then in your child modules you don't need to re-add those exclusions which can help if the same dependencies (and hence exclusions) are used in different pom files.

Comment: I assume you are talking about #4 then...technically it has a progress bar while downloading jars(and I am not sure why it keeps doing that as there is only two snapshot jars included) but I can't do anything which is really frustrating.  #1 was not a hang but rather can't run JUnit test since the .class file is not in target/classes and of course compile can take a bit to catch up with a large number of classes.