# in maven how to log the command that was run?

Tags: maven

We are getting stack overflow with the aspectj compiler in maven so naturally, I want to log the exact command line command that was run (Much like ant can do) so that I can run it and attach the debugger to the command that is run.  How do I do this in maven?

```
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:427)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:393)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:427)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:393)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:427)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:393)
```

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get extra debug information from Maven, use the `-X` option.  This typically logs command lines of all spawned processes such as the compiler.  This will produce a lot of output from all plugins.

If you are using the [AspectJ Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), the command line is saved to a file defined by the [argumentFileName](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#argumentFileName) parameter of the plugin, which defaults to `builddef.lst` in the project's build output directory (which is by default `target`).  This might be a useful and easier alternative than scanning the large amount of debugging output of Maven.